# Loading JMapViewer from a specified zoom level

Tags: java, zooming, jmapviewer

I am trying to load `JMapViewer` from a specified zoom level for my offline use. I have been able to load the tiles from my local machine from `zoom levels 1 to 18 and render` it well. The `JMapViewer` works well only when `minimum zoom level is 0 , 1, 2 or 3`. Suppose I change the minimum zoom level to anything `greater than 3`, the J`MapViewer` throws a `null pointer` exception while trying to get the position while drawing the tiles and the program doesn't start at all. Is there any way to load them from a particular zoom after making a code change.

The following are the links I've referred to:

> http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/viewer/jmapviewer/src/org/openstreetmap/gui/jmapviewer/
>
> http://josm.openstreetmap.de/query?col=id&col=summary&col=type&col=status&col=priority&col=milestone&col=component&col=time&order=id&report=2
>
> http://paulusschoutsen.nl/blog/2012/08/java-component-jmapviewer-with-offline-openstreetmap-support/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I figured it out. In JMapViewer.java, we need to specify the minimum zoom level as a parameter to OfflineOsmTileSource. Then we need to specify setDisplayPosition(tileSource.LonToX((lon1 + lon2) / 2, zoom_level),tileSource.LatToY((lat1 + lat2)/2, zoom_level), zoom_level);

Hope it helps somebody.

Cheers!